# Segmentation fault 11: gdb reason 13

Tags: c++, memory

Here is my code:

```
int main(){

long userInput;
long placeArray[userInput +1];
long divisionPlace, modPlace;
long number = userInput;
long two = 2;

cout << "enter: ";
cin >> userInput;


for (int i = 1; i < userInput; i++) {
    divisionPlace = number / two;
    modPlace = number % two;
    placeArray[number - i ] = modPlace;
}

for (int i = 0; i < userInput; i++) {
    cout << placeArray[i] << " ";
}
cout <<endl;

return 0;
}
```

Can someone point out my error in the code as to why I am mishandling memory?

Comment: You're using `userInput` uninitialized. You should get a compiler warning for that if you turn the warnings on.

Comment: The uninitialized `userInput` is definitely the root problem, but note also you're using the uninitialized `userInput` to a) attempt to determine the amount of storage for `placeArray`, and b) initialize `number`, which while technically not used uninitialized, is essentially randomly initialized. Since `number` is not reliably intialized, then `placeArray[number - i]` makes no sense, either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As was mentioned in a comment, you're using `userInput` before it's initialized here:

```
long placeArray[userInput +1];
```

So `placeArray` is not going to have the size you expect it to when you access it in the loop below.  This will lead to writing to memory you didn't allocate, and will mess up your stack.

Comment: Thanks obvious mistake I made. Too much going on smh...

Answer (score 1):

Your array is allocated incorrectly.

```
long userInput;

cout << "enter: "; 
cin >> userInput; 

if (userInput <= 0)
{
   cerr << "error" << endl;
   exit(1);
}

long* placeArray = new long[userInput +1]; 

long divisionPlace, modPlace; 
long number = userInput; 
long two = 2; 

for (int i = 1; i < userInput; i++) { 
    divisionPlace = number / two; 
    modPlace = number % two; 
    placeArray[number - i ] = modPlace; 
} 

for (int i = 0; i < userInput; i++) { 
    cout << placeArray[i] << " "; 
} 
cout <<endl; 

delete [] placeArray;
```

Comment: Not sure that's right either... Surely you really only need to allocate about `log10(userInput)` array elements... Otherwise, I'ma make your machine's virtual memory system die a slow, horrible death...

Comment: LOL @twalberg I just allocated as much mem as the OP supposedly wanted. Maybe the purpose of his program is to let users test random memory allocations.